# Spring can't find bean named entityManagerFactory

Tags: spring, jpa, entitymanager

I have a web application that uses spring and hibernate for JPA support, but when I open my Index page this exception happens:

http://pastebin.com/0X1GG9GQ

But I think my applicationContext.xml is well configured, but I'm posting it anyways just to be sure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            ">

    <!-- properties file for jdbc database access details / -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.maegul" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="maegul"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:database="${jpa.database}" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}" />

</beans>
```

I really don't know what's wrong, I've been changing little things to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** (Long Stack in pastebin for easier reading...)

Changed some things in the ApplicationContext.xml and now I get a different stack trace:

```
INFO  - Server                     - jetty-7.5.0.v20110901
INFO  - tandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for {}, did not find {}
INFO  - /                          - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Nov 06 13:22:53 COT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@40871449: defining beans [maegulApplication,itemService,userService,cartItemDao,mediaItemDao,mediaSourceDao,passwordDao,userDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@40871449: defining beans [maegulApplication,itemService,userService,cartItemDao,mediaItemDao,mediaSourceDao,passwordDao,userDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR - ContextLoader              - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.maegul.data.dao.impl.MediaItemDao com.maegul.service.implementation.ItemFindService.mediaItemDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaItemDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
```

Rest of stack here: http://pastebin.com/u82n3C5n

I see that the Annotations I made are getting recognized, but it looks like it can't still find an entityManagerFactory. One thing I've seen is that maybe instead of using `@PersistenceContext` should I use `@PersistenceUnit` in my `EntityManager` fields, but I dont know...

**EDIT 2**

All my DAO implementations look like this:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.maegul.data.dao.AbstractDAO;
import com.maegul.data.entities.MediaItem;

@Repository(value = "mediaItemDao")
public class MediaItemDaoImpl extends AbstractDAO<MediaItem> implements
        MediaItemDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.maegul.data.dao.DAO#getEntityManager()
     */
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.maegul.data.dao.DAO#getClazz()
     */
    public Class<MediaItem> getClazz() {
        return MediaItem.class;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.maegul.data.dao.impl.MediaItemDao#findByName(java.lang.String)
     */
    public MediaItem findByName(String name) {
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "select u from " + getClazz() + " where u.name = :name");
        q.setParameter("name", name);

        return (MediaItem) q.getSingleResult();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.maegul.data.dao.impl.MediaItemDao#findByType(java.lang.String)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<MediaItem> findByType(String type) {
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from " + getClazz() + " where u.type = :type");
        q.setParameter("type", type);

        return q.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

This is the AbstractDAO class: http://pastebin.com/f2BQG9RE

And this is the DAO interface, which is implemented by AbstractDAO: http://pastebin.com/h7dAHTTC

and this is the Interface MEdiaItemDao:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.maegul.data.dao.DAO;
import com.maegul.data.entities.MediaItem;

public interface MediaItemDao extends DAO<MediaItem>{

    MediaItem findByName(String name);

    List<MediaItem> findByType(String type);
}
```

Comment: Every thing looks fine. Check that the server is correct and starts correct. Check that `applicationContext.xml` is really loaded in the spring root application context. And if this does not help, set a breakpoint in OpenEntitzMangerInViewFilter class.

Comment: @Ralph thanks for your response, the ApplicationContext.xml is being loaded, just look at the new stack I got, but it still doesn't load the `EntityManeager` so I don't know what to do

Comment: please post the `mediaItemDao`, and if it is wired via xml, then the according pice of xml too.

Comment: @Ralph Its wired via annotations, not via xml

Comment: Do you have an own implementation of EntityManger?

Comment: @Ralph no it's the default JPA implementation

Comment: I mean not the interface of MediaItemDao, I mean its implementation (`com.maegul.data.dao.impl.MediaItemDao`) . We need to see if the injection is correct.

Comment: @Ralph look at edit 2, there is what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry I have no idea everything looks ok, I do not understand why the EntityManger is not injected. The only thing we have not checked so fare, is that there is an second MediaItemDao instance created in the WebContext. Please check that in the webContext in no second ComponentScan that instancitate a second MediaItemDao

Comment: Is your persistence unit located in the default locaiton?

<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />

Comment: yep it is in that position, I managed to fix the problem by making a new project and copying everything exactly the same, guess eclipse was being moody...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only needed a project clean, so I did and it fixed it.